# iBeacon: Settings of CLBeaconRegion identifier?

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, ios8, core-location, ibeacon

I use Apple [AirLocate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html) demo App to create an iBeacon.

- Identifier: com.example.apple-samplecode.AirLocate
- UUID: E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0
- Major: 0
- Minor: 0
- Measured Power: -59

The signal is **successfully** picked up by an Android beacon detector App.

However, when I use the following codes to detect the iBeacon in iOS 8, the beacon does not show up:

```
self.coreLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_coreLocation.delegate = self;
NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.example.apple-samplecode.AirLocate.%@", @"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"];
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:identifier];
if(region) {
    region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    region.notifyOnExit = YES;
    [_coreLocation startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
```

No matter which value I use in the identifier field, the beacon is never found by `CLLocationManager`. Its delegates, `didDetermineState:` and `didRangeBeacons:` were never been called. However, delegate `monitoringDidFailForRegion` received this:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 4.)

After looked up some documentations online, the error code 4 means:

> Access to the region monitoring service was denied by the user.

But I use the following codes to prove my app is authorized to monitor region:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"didChangeAuthorizationStatus: Denied");
    } else if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        NSLog(@"didChangeAuthorizationStatus: Not Determined");
    } else if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
        NSLog(@"didChangeAuthorizationStatus: Authorized Always");
    } else if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        NSLog(@"didChangeAuthorizationStatus: Authorized When In Use");
    } else if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
        NSLog(@"didChangeAuthorizationStatus: Restricted");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"didChangeAuthorizationStatus: Unknown");
    }
}
```

and it returns:

> didChangeAuthorizationStatus: Authorized When In Use

Given that:

- I'm using iPhone 5s with iOS 8.1.2
- I added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `Info.plist`
- In Capabilities page, I enabled "Location updates" and "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" (Xcode added corresponding entries to `Info.plist`)
- Requested "When In Use" Authorization via `[self.coreLocation requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`
- Allowed "Location Service" and "Push Notification" during first launch of the App
- Airplane Mode is OFF
- Bluetooth is ON
- Wi-Fi is ON, connected to Internet
- Settings > General > Background App Refresh is ON
- Settings > Privacy > Locations Services > My App > While Using (tick)
- `[CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLRegion class]]` returns YES

What did I miss to cause this error 4 ? Also, does the identifier necessary to match with the iBeacon's Bundle Identifier (why Android can detect all beacons, but iOS need to specify identifiers)?

Reference: [Region Monitoring and iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)

Comment: Try to add  [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion]; 
[_locationManager requestStateForRegion:beaconRegion];
And  make sure that NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription is added corruptly. Your code looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Try an off the shelf iOS detector from the AppStore like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) to eliminate a hardware issue.
2. If the above works, try uninstalling and reinstalling your app.  I have seen the location permission get screwed up if the authorization code was added after the app was already run.

Also, it may be helpful to post your Info.plist in case there is an issue there.

Comment: Rebooting the device resolved the permission issue. Don't know why.